# Remove compiler optimizations and enable pdb files in release

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a qt pro file, in which I want to disable optimizations, because I see some unreasonable crashes. Therefore I use the options:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -O
```

What is more, I need to produce pdb files, while building in release mode, to trace any crush afterword. Therefore, I am using the following option in my pro file:

```
CONFIG += force_debug_info
```

However, I see during compilation that because of the second option, the compiler adds the O2 optimizations. Do you know why this is happening and how I can have both functionalities?

Comment: After you remove optimizations from release build and add debug info, what's the difference between it and a normal debug build?

Comment: Could you perhaps show a [mcve] of the misbehaving program? Then we would perhaps be able to spot your bug.

Comment: You don't need to disable optimizations to produce debug info (actually disabling them may let bug go away). Just use `-g3`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The release build with debug info, will give me a release executable, which I can install on our client pc and also give me pdb files to load when a new dump file is created, after a crash. The normal debug needs dependancies from debug dlls which are only found in development environment.

Comment: @VTT: Of course there is no need to disable compiler optimizations to produce debug info, I just have to because I have several crashes with options enabled the options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that when building with debug information, the qmake flag to update in the pro file is:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO
```

Therefore, I should write:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -O1
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -O
```